# RSelenium Error: Timeout of 60 seconds was reachedError in open.connection(con, "rb")

Tags: r, google-chrome, scrape, rselenium

I'm new here but I got a lot of help from this community over the past. Thanks so much for all you guys. Just before I updated my rstudio and r. But suddenly I cannot open a selenium session with the following error:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
Warning: URL 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/selenium-release/o': Timeout of 60 seconds was reachedError in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/selenium-release/o'
```

Please help me out. I've tried search for relevant error message but got nothing. Thanks!

I am expecting to start a new Rselenium session.

Comment: I've tried all below but none worked.

`rD <- rsDriver()`

`rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",  chromever = "100.0.4896.60")`

`rD <- rsDriver(port = 4685L, version = "latest", browser=c("chrome"), chromever = "101.0.4951.41")`

`rD <- rsDriver(port= sample(7600)[1], browser=c("firefox"), chromever = NULL)
`

Comment: Also I am using Clash for Windows to access Google. Is it because of that? I've tried using Global proxy but still no use

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your code is failing to download the drivers needed, this is most likely a proxy issue with the `httr` package. It sounds like you have used Selenium before so you should have some drivers installed already. Running your previous attempts of `rsDriver()` with `check = FALSE` might circumvent that step.

Comment: Hi, @bingbongtelecom , thanks for your response. When I tried 

`rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
               check = FALSE,
               port = 191L
               )
`

I got the following error 

`Error: version is not a character vector
`

Yes, I have used selenium before. But I updated almost everything (r, studio, package) recently, would it be possible that I deleted them all before?

Comment: To me that error looks like it's missing a driver. Can you run the following 4 commands? `binman::list_versions("chromedriver")`, `binman::list_versions("geckodriver")`, `binman::list_versions("seleniumserver")`, `binman::list_versions("phantomjs")`

Comment: Also, please run and send the output of this `wdman::selenium(retcommand = T, check = F)`

Comment: Hi @bingbongtelecom, thanks for your help

```{r}
binman::list_versions("chromedriver") 
binman::list_versions("geckodriver")
binman::list_versions("seleniumserver") 
binman::list_versions("phantomjs")
```

The following from above

mac64
 [1] "100.0.4896.60"  "101.0.4951.15"  "101.0.4951.41"  "102.0.5005.27" 
 [5] "102.0.5005.61"  "103.0.5060.134" "103.0.5060.24"  "103.0.5060.53" 
 [9] "104.0.5112.20"  "104.0.5112.29" 

$macos
[1] "0.30.0" "0.31.0"

$generic
[1] "3.141.59"      "4.0.0-alpha-1" "4.0.0-alpha-2"

$macosx
[1] "2.0.0" "2.1.1" "2.5.0"

Comment: ```wdman::selenium(retcommand = T, check = F)```

gives ```Error: version is not a character vector```, the same error

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Sorry for more steps but could you run these three tests. It will help say which driver is causing this issue. `wdman::selenium(retcommand = T,chromever = NULL, check = F)` `wdman::selenium(retcommand = T,geckover = NULL, check = F)` `wdman::selenium(retcommand = T,chromever = NULL,geckover = NULL, check = F)`

Comment: Thanks for your help @bingbongtelecom :)

For `wdman::selenium(retcommand = T, chromever = NULL, check = F)`, it returns `Error: version is not a character vector`.

Comment: For `wdman::selenium(retcommand = T, geckover = NULL, check = F)`, it returns `[1] "/usr/bin/java character(0) -Dphantomjs.binary.path='/Users/tonygong/Library/Application Support/binman_phantomjs/macosx/2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs' -jar '/Users/tonygong/Library/Application Support/binman_seleniumserver/generic/4.0.0-alpha-2/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-2.jar' -port 4567"`

Comment: for `wdman::selenium(retcommand = T, chromever = NULL, geckover = NULL, check = F)`, it returns `[1] "/usr/bin/java -Dphantomjs.binary.path='/Users/tonygong/Library/Application Support/binman_phantomjs/macosx/2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs' -jar '/Users/tonygong/Library/Application Support/binman_seleniumserver/generic/4.0.0-alpha-2/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-2.jar' -port 4567"`

Comment: `rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", check = FALSE, port = 4567L, chromever=NULL )` 
 can you try this?

Comment: Hi @bingbongtelecom, thank you for your reply. Still the same error...`Error: version is not a character vector`

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. The Firefox driver is causing the issue not the chrome one. Can you try `rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", check = FALSE, port = 4567L, geckover=NULL, chromever = '104.0.5112.29') `

Comment: Hi @bingbongtelecom thank you! the error now is `Error in chrome_ver(chromecheck[["platform"]], chromever) : 
  version requested doesnt match versions available = `, I have tried changing the chromever but didn't work

Comment: Hi Tony I apologize but I will not be able to look at this over the next few days. I am not sure what is causing the incompatibility but please search using your new error code. Some suggestions I’ve seen are updating Java and making sure the Chrome version matches your driver version

Comment: Hi @bingbongtelecom, thank you so much for your help and suggestions. Really appreciate this. I'll comment later if I got the answer. Thanks!